# Extract / lookup details on positions of 3D models in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, 3d, gps, maps, google-earth

I am a novice programmer, but I am trying to find a way to query information *about* 3D objects that are in Google Maps/Earth - specifically, information such their GPS position(s), height, external sides, volume of the objects.

In my research, [I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520754/how-to-retrieve-3d-models-from-google-earth) that I can't extract the 3D objects themselves, but I just want to obtain information about them - such as the GPS position of vertices.
Is there a way to do this through standard APIs?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to be able to get information in the same way as the Google Maps Elevation API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734826/is-it-possible-to-display-3d-data-in-google-maps-or-google-earth), it might give you an idea about your problem.

Comment: Thanks KENdi - a key point is that Google Maps is 2D, and Google Earth is 3D.
However, the Google Earth API is not deprecated and not going to be available soon, so I am now looking in to Cesium.
Anyone else have some ideas or help?